# Login with Google Plus on My Website

Tags: php, google-plus

I'm very new to web development. I have searched for login with Google plus and found several good tutorials. But they seems to be very old (most of them from 2011). Why?

I tried below code chunks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
   $("#packagesGrid").load('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=ya29.ahes6zt9yv2qaeej5ycn21fn9maokp15scwqkcal3guqxxez7odtjg&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600');    
</script>
```

I just manually copy pasted the token to the url on the jQuery load function. But nothing is filled to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in a Google presentation at the moment and apparently they have just launched [Google+ sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/), which allows you to do stuff like this much more elegantly.

I don't know any more about it than that, really, but it certainly seems worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Owen, It seems good as you stated. I'll give a try and update you.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha Thanks; I'd certainly be interested to know if it's as good as it sounds (and I don't have a project I can try it out on at the moment)

Answer (score 7):

Google APIs use the **OAuth 2.0** protocol for authentication and authorization. Google supports several OAuth 2.0 flows that cover common web server, JavaScript, device, installed application, and server to server scenarios. The Previous Versions of OAuth has been deprecated by Google.

**Here is how it works** : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

**To Get Started with Coding**,

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-php-starter/

Just download  the project and Follow the steps mentioned.

I have tried this recently and it's working **100%** fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making use of the following tutorial [Login with Google Account OAuth](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/login-with-google-account-oauth.html). It explains calling the correct methods and saves the user data to your database. Plus it was published today.

Comment: I tried this also, But this takes long time to complete the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use google client Api library for php

and after that,  you need to generate some key (like client id, client secret key, simple API key for Google)

then you have to use these API and use the keys generated. You can find the complete procedure and documents at there corresponding websites...

If you neeed the working tutorial.