# Enable Registration of a Form only if you are logged into Google

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration form ready which is completely functional. 
What I need now is that the users must be signed in from their Google Account before they can submit the form. This step is to ensure the authenticity of the user.

I have enabled Sign-In Using google, But am unable to proceed further

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="964441361771-o54lshie0mvgufergku9a35oi8o3bl1n.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
<script>
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
  };
</script>
```

My PHP code that retrieves information from HTML page

```
    $fullname= $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender']; // 0 for male, 1 female
$sem    = $_POST['semester']; //roll is semester
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact']; 
$address = $_POST['address'];
$pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
$source  = $_POST['source'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$passno  = $_POST['passno'];
 $pass_end  = $_POST['pass_end'];
 $voucher  = $_POST['voucher'];
 $season  = $_POST['season'];   
$classof = $_POST['classof'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$branch  =  $_POST['branch'];
$year    = $_POST['year'];
$age    = $_POST['dob'];
$dateofentry = date("Y-m-d");
```

I then insert these values into my database after performing some checks on the user entered data

```
     $q = mysqli_prepare($db,"INSERT INTO student(id,fullname,gender,semester,email,DOB,contact,aadhar,address,pincode,
 source,destination,passno,pass_end,voucher,season,classof,duration,branch,year,img_loc,dateofentry) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)") OR die($q->error);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q,"isiissiisisssssissssss",$empty,$fullname,$gender,$sem,$email,$age,$contact,$aadhar,$address,$pincode,$source,$destination,$passno,$pass_end,$voucher,$season,$classof,$duration,$branch,$year,$TargetPath,$dateofentry);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login with Google Plus on My Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559217/login-with-google-plus-on-my-website)

Comment: Since you have tagged this PHP, is there any PHP code you can show us?