# How To Login Through Google Plus in PHP

Tags: php, google-signin

Fatal error: Class 'Google_client' not found

```
<?php  
    require_once "Google/vendor/autoload.php";
    $client = new Google_client();
    $client->setAuthConfig("client_credentials.json");
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_LOGIN);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
    $client->setRedirectUri("http://www.georeachtech.com/garagenu/gmail.php");
?>
```

Comment: Change the name as 'new Google_Client();' and check it. have you called the Google_Client file in the above file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login with Google Plus on My Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559217/login-with-google-plus-on-my-website)